# How to count word frequency from a Pandas Dataframe- Python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, text-mining

I currently created a Pandas Dataframe from a dictionary.
The Dataframe looks something like:

```
      URL         TITLE
0   /xxxx.xx   Hi this is word count
1   /xxxx.xx   Hi this is Stack Overflow
2   /xxxx.xx   Stack Overflow Questions
```

I want to add a new column to this table, which lists the number of frequency the word "Stack Overflow" appears. So for example, it would be like:

```
      URL         TITLE                          COUNT
0   /xxxx.xx   Hi this is word count               0
1   /xxxx.xx   Hi this is Stack Overflow           1
2   /xxxx.xx   Stack Overflow Questions            1
```

The `count` function does not seem to work for dictionaries, but only for strings.  Would there bean easy way to do this?

Comment: Can you show the dictionary and the code for creating the table

Comment: Is this a pandas dataframe?

Comment: "Stack Overflow" is not a word, it is two words. What if the string contains "Overflow Stack" or "Notstack Overflow"?

Comment: @Jan Yes it is a dictionary that I converted into a pandas dataframe. I will try to further clarify the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this is actually a `pandas dataframe`, you could do:

```
import pandas as pd

table = {   'URL': ['/xxxx.xx', '/xxxx.xx', '/xxxx.xx'], 
            'TITLE': ['Hi this is word count', 'Hi this is Stack Overflow', 'Stack Overflow Questions']}

df = pd.DataFrame(table)
df['COUNT'] = df.TITLE.str.count('Stack Overflow')
print(df)
```

This yields:

```
                       TITLE       URL  COUNT
0      Hi this is word count  /xxxx.xx      0
1  Hi this is Stack Overflow  /xxxx.xx      1
2   Stack Overflow Questions  /xxxx.xx      1
```

Answer (score 1):

The `count()` method on dataframes is good at counting occurrences of a single values such as "Stack Overflow".

To do frequency analysis of multiple values, consider using [`collection.Counter(data)`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html#counter-objects) and its [`.most_common(k)`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) method.